# How is the 1D transient heat conduction equation derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differential-equations, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

From my book:

> $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial^2 t}$$
>
> with an initial condition and boundary conditions
>   $$T(x,0)=T_0$$
>   $$T(L,t)=T_0$$
>   $$-k\left.\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0}=2A\cos^2\left(\frac{\omega t}{2}\right)=A(\cos\omega t+1)$$
>
> where $A=V_0^2/(8RhL)$, $V_0$ is the voltage applied to the heater, $R$ the electrical resistance of the heater, $h$ the thickness of the thin film, $\alpha$ the thermal diffusivity of the thin film, and $\omega/2$ the heating frequency. The solution for this problem is
>
> $$T(x,t)-T_0=\frac Ak\sqrt{\frac\alpha\omega}\exp\left (-\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2\alpha}}x\right)\\ \times\cos\left(\omega t-\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2\alpha}}x-\frac\pi4\right)-\frac Ak(x-L)$$

I'm trying to derive how he came to the solution from the boundary conditions because the final solution doesn't contain any Fourier transformation and eigenvalues. There is no derivation in the paper, and I searched books and the internet thoroughly but couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Gert I have tried conventional method of variable separation and fourier transformation. but all my answers contains eigenvalues and a fourier series, which this solution (in pic) does not contain.

Comment: [This page](http://john.maloney.org/thermal_actuation.htm) (disclaimer: my site) solves a similar problem. I remember working from a great handbook on PDEs that assembled a variety of methods; will try to track it down.

Comment: You should type out relevant parts of text rather than post pictures of the text. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: @Chemomechanics . Thank you! That helps. I too got something similar to the solution in your website and my solutions contain eigenvalues. But the solution in the pic I uploaded is different because it doesn’t contain eigenvalues, but contains a phase term in cos(). I'd really appreciate if you could tell me what that handbook was :)

Comment: Found it: Farlow's *Partial differential equations for scientists and engineers*, the most straightforward text I've found on PDEs. Section 7, which addresses "Heat-flow problems with derivative boundary conditions," discusses Chester's solution.

Comment: I should also mention that the authors of your article make the unstated assumption that the ratio $\omega/\alpha$ is large so that the length of the sample L does not come into play in the oscillatory part of the solution; the oscillatory part of the solution is damped out spatially toward the end close to x << L. We know this because L does not appear in their oscillatory terms.

Answer (score 6):

What they have done is focus exclusively on the long-time solution when the system has reached "oscillatory steady state."  This solution does not feature any exponentially decaying terms in time.

So their solution for the temperature is taken to be of the form:  $$T(x,t)-T_0=\alpha(x)\cos(\omega t-\phi)+\beta(x)\sin(\omega t-\phi)+\frac{A}{k}(L-x)$$where $\phi$ is the phase shift between the heat flux time variation and the temperature time variation.  They solve for $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ subject to the boundary conditions.  So, they're basically not forcing themselves to satisfy the initial condition.

Try this form of the solution and see what you get.

Comment: Very interesting, Chester. +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you; this is a very good suggestion, let me try this particular solution method!

Comment: Show us more of the details of what you did.  I've solve many oscillatory steady state problems in heat transfer and mass transfer using this approach, and it was always successful.

Comment: Tried to solve by taking $$T(x,t)−T_0={\alpha(x)}cos(\omega t)+{\beta(x)}sin(\omega t)+\frac Ak(x-L)$$ as a particular solution
${\alpha(x)}$  and ${\beta(x)}$ values was found by first two conditions ${T(x,0)=T_o}$ and ${T(L,t)=T_0}$. Where ${\beta(x)}$ become zero. But the third condition remain unsused and also it doesn't provide the solution mentioned in the question. Can you tell me if you got the same solution as the question?

Comment: Like I said.  Please show us the details.  Your application of the boundary conditions is definitely incorrect.

Comment: The differential equations I solved were $$\frac{d^2\alpha}{dx^2}=+\frac{\omega}{\kappa}\beta$$ and $$\frac{d^2\beta}{dx^2}=-\frac{\omega}{\kappa}\alpha$$ Is that what you ended up with?

Comment: Yes, I got something similar.
After applying the particular solution to the heat equation, I get
$${-a(x)\omega\sin(\omega t)+b(x)\omega\cos(\omega t) = \alpha cos(\omega t)\frac{d^2 a(x)}{dx^2}+\alpha sin(\omega t)\frac{d^2 b(x)}{dx^2}}$$
Separating the coefficient finally end up
$${\alpha\frac{d^2 a(x)}{dx^2}=\omega b(x)}$$ and
$${\alpha\frac{d^2 b(x)}{dx^2}=-\omega a(x)}$$
But how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90792/discussion-between-betsy-and-chester-miller).